# Angularjs pagination as service or factory

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible for me create a service or factory for the pagination, so i wont have to code it in every controller that need the pagination?

i have pagination as below :

**controller**

```
$scope.Find = function(){

    $scope.Tablelist = {};
    $scope.ShowPagination = false;    
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost/api/warehouse/matinclist.php",

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      $scope.Tablelist = response.data;
      $scope.ShowPagination = true;
    }, function(response){
      $scope.ShowPagination = false;
      console.log("failed");
    })
  }

  $scope.itemsPerPage = 12;
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.range = function() {
    var rangeSize = 8;
    var ps = [];
    var start;

    start = $scope.currentPage;
    //  console.log($scope.pageCount(),$scope.currentPage)
    if ( start > $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize ) {
      start = $scope.pageCount()-rangeSize+1;
    }

    for (var i=start; i<start+rangeSize; i++) {
      if(i>=0)
      ps.push(i);
    }
    return ps;
  };
  $scope.prevPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
      $scope.currentPage--;
    }
  };
  $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === 0 ? "disabled" : "";
  };
  $scope.pageCount = function() {
    return Math.ceil($scope.Tablelist.length/$scope.itemsPerPage)-1;
  };
  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pageCount()) {
      $scope.currentPage++;
    }
  };
  $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {
    return $scope.currentPage === $scope.pageCount() ? "disabled" : "";
  };
  $scope.setPage = function(n) {
    $scope.currentPage = n;
  };
```

I am looking to create the pagination as an factory, so i just inject them if i  need to use it in any controllers.

Please help how should i do it.

Comment: You can write it as a directive like [bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)

Comment: care to give some guides?

Comment: That depends on your understanding on directive. If you understand how to write a directive, it should be obvious that you need to write a isolate scoped directive for this, and what should be passed into the scope, or at least figure out by referencing bootstrap pagination. If you are not confident enough to write one, you can start by using bootstrap directive and see how it functions.